# XCode 6.3.3: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: xcode

I'm recently new at my company and have just picked up a project that was last worked on three years ago. It's written in Objective-C in an old version of XCode, and I had to upgrade to version 6.3.3. It's currently set to simulate on iPhone6. I'm getting an error that I've been trying to solve all day, this is the error message shown:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ccCardinalSplineAt(CGPoint, CGPoint, CGPoint, CGPoint, double, float)", referenced from:
  _ccDrawCardinalSpline in CCDrawingPrimitives.o
```

Function call:

```
CGPoint newPos = ccCardinalSplineAt( pp0, pp1, pp2, pp3, tension, lt);
```

Declaration (.m file):

```
inline CGPoint ccCardinalSplineAt( CGPoint p0, CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2, CGPoint p3, CGFloat tension, ccTime t ) {
    //A bunch of math and just assigning variables that is probably irrelevant
    return ccp(x,y);
}
```

Declaration (.h file):

```
CGPoint ccCardinalSplineAt( CGPoint p0, CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2, CGPoint p3, CGFloat tension, ccTime t );
```

As of now, I have tried changing the architectures, changing the files to use in the Compile Sources (replacing .h with its associated .m and vice-versa), ensured that all framework files in the Link Binary With Libraries section are all loaded and not red, cleaning the project and its build folder, and deleting derived data.

There is also an error of being unable to generate the .app.dSYM file, but I assume this would probably be solved once the first problem is handled. Please tell me if this is not the case and I'll post the error here.

If you would be able to help solve this problem it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How and where is `ccTime` declared?  Does `ccDrawCardinalSpline` live in the same file as `ccCardinalSplineAt`, and if not, does the source for `ccDrawCardinalSpline` include the header for `ccCardinalSplineAt`?

Comment: 1. in "ccTypes.h" which is now imported in the files which include ccDrawCardinalSpline and ccCardinalSplineAt. It's written as `typedef float ccTime;`. Changing it to a double to match tension did not solve the problem.
2. The source file for ccDrawCardinalSpline does import the .h file for ccCardinalSplineAt's source.